# PhpStorm - xDebug on demand not attaching

Tags: phpstorm, xdebug

I tried out your new feature "xedbug on demand". I stuck to these guides (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.3/configuring-xdebug.html and https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2016/06/xdebug-on-demand-for-cli-php-scripts-in-phpstorm-2016-2-eap/).

I see that in the php Server menu when I add the path to the xdebug that PhpStorm recognizes it (the label switches from "not installed" to "XDebugger 2.4.1").

So everything seems to be fine but when I use the debugger via the bug-icon, it never attaches/stops for the breakpoint.

I activated the xdebug-Logfile, but it stays completely empty.

Furthermore I commented everything xdebug-related out in the php.ini.

The xdebug-port is still on 9000 (default).

Any ideas what I can do about it?

**Update: I'm using the debugger via phpStorm's "PHP Web Application" and the debug-icon. I'm debugging php files which are executed via an apache vHost.**

PS: Checked IntelliJ forum and Stack posts, didn't find anything helpful though...

Comment: Please provide details -- what are you trying to debug etc; Screenshots please.

Comment: @LazyOne Updated my post. There is nothing to screenshot afaik

Comment: That's enough info

Comment: P.S. Consider adding your updates at the very end of your initial question .. or at least make it more clear (bold font for  "UPDATE" or similar stuff) that will make it easier to find it.

Comment: Good remark, too late now but still edited my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Xdebug in demand" option **works for CLI debugging only** (Run/Debug Configuration of "PHP Script" type; will also work for other CLI-mode configs, e.g. "PHPUnit") be it local or remote.

Quote from the aforementioned [introduction blog post](https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2016/06/xdebug-on-demand-for-cli-php-scripts-in-phpstorm-2016-2-eap/):

> To use the great new feature, first, you need to disable Xdebug for **command line PHP scripts**.

---

**That option does not work for web pages served via web browser** (e.g. Apache/nginx/IIS) or when just listening for any incoming debug connections ([Zero-config approach](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/zero-configuration-debugging.html)) where actual debug is initiated outside of IDE.

**The reason is very simple:** when launching debugger for CLI script, IDE launches your php executable (your configured PHP Interpreter, e.g. `php.exe` on Windows) with additional parameter (`-z`: check `php --help` output or [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php)) that can load such additional extension.

But when you debugging a web page then whole PHP is not controlled by PhpStorm: it's your web server (Apache/nginx/IIS/etc) that communicates with PHP .. and you cannot pass such arguments at this stage.