# Configuring Xdebug for using zero-configuration debugging in Intellij

Tags: php, debugging, intellij-idea, phpstorm, xdebug

I'm using Intellij IDEA 2016.3.3 with the PHP-plugin of PhpStorm in Linux Mint 18. I try to configure Xdebug for using zero-configuration debugging. I followed the [official guide](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.3/configuring-xdebug.html) and [this](https://youtu.be/OlcsQ8TCU3A) video tutorial. However, the debugger does not stop at any breakpoint.

**/opt/lampp/etc/php.ini** (extract)

```
[Xdebug]
zend_extension = /opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20151012/xdebug.so
xdebug.default_enable=1
xdebug.idekey=Intellij
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
```

[image]
[image: debug settings screenshot]

I [generated Xdebug & Zend Debugger bookmarklets](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/marklets/) with IDE key `Intellij`.

**Workflow:**

1. Intellij: *Run > Start Listening for PHP Debug Connections*
2. I open a PHP-file of my PHP-project in Intellij that I'd like to debug.
3. I add a breakpoint
4. I open the file in the browser by clicking on the Google Chrome icon in the top-right corner
5. I click on the *Start debugger* bookmarklet in Google Chrome
6. I reload the page
7. I expect the debugger to stop at the breakpoint, but it doesn't

[image]

[image: php.info]

Comment: Sorry .. but "On Demand" works for CLI debugging only (will not work for web-based requests). More here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41679261/783119

Comment: I guess this restriction has changed. The video tutorial shows how to debug a web-based request.

Comment: Please state exact time on that video. Right now (I have not watched it yet) it could be completely different thing

Comment: You are right. "On Demand" works for CLI debugging only. The approach that I'm actually trying to use is [zero-configuration debugging](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Zero-configuration+Web+Application+Debugging+with+Xdebug+and+PhpStorm). I'll change the title.

Comment: 1) Have a look at this link in case if you have not seen it yet: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Debugging+with+PhpStorm 2) If still the same -- please provide more details: OS; `phpinfo();` output captured via browser (top header table + actual xdebug section0; check hat you have no symlinks in the path; Is that local debug or some sort of VM/remote is involved; xdebug log for such unsuccessful session: https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#remote_log

Comment: It works if I'm using the Apache server, but it does not work if I use Intellij's web server (see workflow 4. I open the file in the browser by clicking on the Google Chrome icon in the top-right corner).

Comment: Please provide phpinfo() output (captured using address where debug does not work) and xdebug log for such unsuccessful session.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what I did, but it suddenly works. I did a restart of Intellij and now it works. I guess that I only did a reload of php.ini in the PHP settings after a relevant change of php.ini, but that didn't affect the build in web server.

@LazyOne Thank you very much for your help and patience.