# How to set up debugger in PhpStorm for a WordPress project running on WAMP

Tags: php, wordpress, wamp, phpstorm, xdebug

To elaborate,

I am trying to setup xdebug on my PhpStorm IDE, but I can't seem to figure it out. What I've done so far:

1.In the project settings, under the `Languages & Frameworks > PHP`, I set the CLI interpreter : PHP 7.10.10

In the same setting, clicking the `...`(browse button), I set the PHP executable `C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.0.10\php.exe` and the debugger extension to `C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.0.10\ext\php_xdebug-2.5.0-7.0-vc14-x86_64.dll`

[image]

2. Now under `Languages & Frameworks > PHP > Servers`, I provide the following,

[image]

Coming from a Java background and being very new to PHP I would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: 1) Please start here in case if you have not seen it yet: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Debugging+with+PhpStorm 2) You do not really need `Use path mappings` if your files are local and no symbolic links are used 3) Specifying PHP Interpreter does not affect web-based debugging at all (when you call your script via browser .. unless you will use PhpStorm's own built-in simple web server .. which is not great option for complex stuff) ... as interpreter is used fro CLI debugging/execution only (it has no influence over PHP that your Apache uses)

Comment: 4) Same for specifying xdebug extension (on demand xdebug loading) -- only works for CLI where you can pass that special extra parm to PHP (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/41679261/783119)

Comment: So .. 1) First confirm that your have xdebug enabled (check `phpinfo();` output captured via browser); 2) Ensure that xdebug is configured (check dedicated `xdebug` section of the aforementioned output). If not sure -- https://xdebug.org/docs/ ; https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Xdebug+Installation+Guide ; 3) Try debugging (from my very first link) 4) https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Troubleshooting+PhpStorm+debugging